# Scrollbars show up when adding element with same size as body

Tags: html, css

When I add an element with the same size (width + height) as the body tag, then I always get (unnecessary?!) horizontal and vertical scrollbars (tested in Chrome and FF).

```
/* css */
html, body {
height: 100%;
width : 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* javascript */
$("<canvas>")
.appendTo("body")
.attr("width", $("body").width())
.attr("height", $("body").height());
```

[Full example at JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/yTwdA/)

Why do those scrollbars show up? The body should be large enough to fit the element without scrollbars.
When removing 4 pixels from the width and height the scrollbars are gone. Why exactly 4 pixels?

Comment: You can use `overflow: hidden;` to remove the scroll bars http://jsfiddle.net/yTwdA/2/ but this will remove scrolling for the whole page

Comment: Of course, but I am more interested in why this happens. Maybe there is an easy explanation (maybe there isn't ;-)).

Comment: maybe add this: `.css({"position":"absolute", "top":"0", "left":"0"});` to your jquery styling

Comment: Interesting :) Try to create `div`, the scrollbars are not appearing, for `<ol>` and `<ul>` only vertical

Answer (score 1):

Would it have something to do with the canvas element having a default padding of 2px?  If you set your css to removing the default margin and padding from the canvas element what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and i get both horizontal and vertical scrolls,i am new and i don't know why that happens but it fixed when i set `overflow-x: 0;` in the body element.
i mean both horizontal and vertical scrolls disappeared. and page get vertical scroll when it has overflow in y axis.